# (F)Lex : get text not matched by rules / get default output

Tags: c++, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I've read a lot about (F)Lex so far, but I couldn't find an answer.
Actually I have 2 questions, and getting the answer for one would be enough.

I have strings like:

```
TOTO 123 CD123 RGF 32/FDS HGGH
```

For each token I find, I put it in a vector. For example, for this string, I get a vector like this:

```
vector = TOTO, whitespace, CD, 123, whitespace, RGF, whitespace, 32, FDS, whitespace, HGGH
```

The "/" does not match any rules, but still, i would like to put it in my vector when I reach it and get:

```
vector = TOTO, whitespace, CD, 123, whitespace, RGF, whitespace, 32, /, FDS, whitespace, HGGH
```

So my questions are:

1) Is there a possibility to modify the default action when an input does not match any rule? (instead of print on stdout ?)

2) If it is not possible, how to catch this ? because here, "/" is an example but it can be everything ( % , C, 3, Blabblabla, etc that does not match my rules), and I can't put

```
 .*   { else();  }
```

cause Flex uses the regex which matches the longest string. I would like that my rules to be "sorted", and ".*" would be the last, like changing the "preferences" of Flex.

Any idea ?

Comment: You could catch a single character. As the last rule it only matches if nothing else matches (it'll never be a longer pattern than any other pattern).

Comment: The thing is, the pattern not matched can be more than one character, like "Blablabla" "%432432432fdsfds" etc...

Comment: For "this" flex, the correct tag is "flex-lexer". You might want to use it.

Comment: Yes, clear. What it does is add a "catch-all" rule and you can collect those characters until you get something else. This can even be done afterwards. You simply add up all non-tokens in your vector. My idea is nothing else than the first answer, that is upvoted

Comment: Thanks Ronald, I didn't get the idea at first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way is to have a rule something like

```
.    { do_something_with_extra_char(*yytext); }
```

at the END of your rules.  This will match any single character (other than newline -- you need a rule that matches newline somewhere too) that doesn't match any other rule.  If you have multiple unmatched characters, this rule will trigger multiple times, but generally that is fine.

Comment: Thanks, combined with Josh answer, it is exactly what I want. I will use that.

But still, isn't it possible to modifiy the default action when nothing is matched -instead of stdout- ?

Comment: That's basically what this is -- the default action always added to the end of your list of rules is just `.|\n  ECHO;`.  If you add other rules such that the default action is never matched (something else always matches first), then you have replaced it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I think [Chris Dodd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22178554/1003855) is better.  Here are two alternative solutions.

One solution would be to use states.  When you read a single unrecognized character, enter into a different state, and build up the unrecognized token.

```
%{
char str[1024];
int strUsed;
%}
%x UNRECOGNIZED
%%
{SOME_RULE} {/* do processing */ }
. {BEGIN(UNRECOGNIZED); str[0] = yytext[0]; strUsed = 1; }
<UNRECOGNIZED>{bad_input} { strcpy(str+strUsed, yytext); strUsed+=yyleng; }
<UNRECOGNIZED>{good_input} { str[strUsed] = 0; vector_add(str); BEGIN(INITIAL); }
```

This solution works well if it's easy to write a regular expression to match "bad" input.  Another solution is to slowly build up bad characters until the next valid match:

```
%{
char str[1024];
int strUsed = 0;
void goodMatch() {
  if(strUsed) {
    str[strUsed] = 0;
    vector_add(str);
    strUsed = 0;
  }
}
%}
%%
{SOME_RULE} { goodMatch(); /* do processing */ }
. {str[strUsed++] = yytext[0]; }
```

Note that this requires you to modify all existing rules to add in a call to function `goodMatch`.

Note for both solutions: if you use a statically sized buffer, you'll have to ensure you don't overflow it on the `strcpy`.  If you end up using a dynamically sized string, you'll have to be sure to correctly clean up memory.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think the best solution is definitely Chris Dodd answer with your goodmatch idea.